# deal with encoding like '\u3046\' in python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a string like `'Earth\u3046\ntroffice' “Vi\u00e4ories”`

What do I do if I want to add space before and after the encoding, to become 
`'Earth \u3046 \ntroffice' and 'Vi \u00e4 ories '`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
" \u00e4 ".join("Vi\u00e4ories".split("\u00e4"))
```

Returns this (with character decoded):

```
'Vi ä ories'
```